# $f\in k(\mathbb{A^2})$ not regular at the origin implies it is not regular at points of a curve passing through the origin.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

This is Exercise 4.12 (a) in [Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry by Reid](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf).

> Prove that any $f \in k(\mathbb{A}^2)$ which is not regular at the origin $(0, 0)$ also fails to be regular at points of a curve passing through $(0, 0)$.

I don't understand this problem. Suppose
$$f=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

Clearly this function is not regular at $(0,0)$. Given a curve $y=\frac{1}{2}x$. Then the function $f$ is regular at every point on this curve except $(0,0)$. Isn't this a counter example of the statement?

I couldn't find what I missed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question doesn't ask you find some curve where it is regular everywhere except the origin. It asks yo to find a curve so that the restriction is NOT regular at most points on the curve.

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you for your reply. So it is asking to find ONE curve passing through the origin such that $f$ is not regular at any points on that curve, correct? I thought it is asking to prove it for all curves, that's why I found a counter example and got confused.

Comment: @Mohan: I understand now. It is not hard to find one curve that satisfies the claim. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just wanted to make one more comment. If you restrict the function to the curve you took ($y=x/2$), then the function becomes constant and thus regular at the origin too.

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you for the comment. Just to confirm, in this problem, does "$f$ fails to be regular at points of a curve" mean "$f$ is not regular when restricted to a curve"? Is it a convention whenever talking about $f$ at points of a curve, it means the restriction of $f$?